# How to search inside nested list object in spring boot data elastic-search

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

My contract model class

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "contract",type = "contract")
public class Contract implements Serializable
{
    @JsonProperty("contract_number")
    @Id
    @Parent(type = "p")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text,index =true)
    private String contract_number;

    private String startDate;

    private String endDate;

    private String supportTypeCode;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested,searchAnalyzer = "true")
        private List<Product> products;
```

My product class

```
@Data
public class Product implements Serializable
{

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String baseNumber;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String rowId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String effectiveDate;
}
```

Using spring data I,m trying to fetch data based on `baseNumber` which is present in product class.
But not able to get data.
I tried using below JPA Method but it is not working.

```
Optional<Contract>  findByProducts_BaseNumber(String s)
```

I am quite confused about how to maintain a mapping between Contract and Product class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me below solution worked I'm using elastic 7.6 version java API.

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("products.baseNumber", baseNumber);
    searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);
    searchSourceBuilder.from(0);
    searchSourceBuilder.size(5);
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.indices(INDEX);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchHits hits = null;
    try
    {
        hits = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT).getHits();
        final List<Contract> collect = Arrays.stream(hits.getHits()).map(
                sourceAsMap -> objectMapper.convertValue(sourceAsMap.getSourceAsMap(), Contract.class)).collect(
                Collectors.toList());
        return  collect.get(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be

```
findByProductsBaseNumber(String s);
```

or

```
findByProducts_BaseNumber(String s);
```

as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Comment: It will not work because elastic 7.5 support is still not present in spring data elastic. I tried your approach.

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 which will be released this spring currently targets ES 7.5.2. But this is not the point. The property in your entity is named _baseNumber_ but you build a query for a property _base**Smart**Number_